# Validate a Sequelize.js model's pseudo column

Tags: validation, model, setter, sequelize.js

It is fairly easy to provide validators for real database columns as part of a model definition.

But how can I validate pseudo columns = pseudo properties through setters defined in the `setterMethods` dict?

Comment: I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1557) on github (sorry can't comment yet).